# Referencing json values from a variable in a different location

Tags: c#

Currently I have the values hard coded in a variable like so:

```
var _studio = new CfnStudio(this, _xStudio.Name, new CfnStudioProps {
     Tags = new [] {
         new CfnTag {        
             Key = "example1",
             Value = "value1"
             },
         new CfnTag {        
             Key = "example2",
             Value = "value2"
             }
     }
 });
```

I'd like to have the `CfnTag`'s defined in a json at a different directory and read them from the above variable.
The json looks like this:

```
{
    "Tags": [
        {
            "Key": "example1",
            "Value": "value1"
        },
        {
            "Key": "example2",
            "Value": "value2"
        }
    ]
}
```

I've read some tutorials on this topic, and if I understand correctly, I can call the json like this:

`string text = File.ReadAllText(@"./tags.json");`

Can I just put this line in the variable (where `Tags = new [] {...` currently is) or is there another approach I should follow?

I'm quite new to C# so the answer might be very obvious.

Comment: You can "deserialize" JSON using `Newtonsoft` nuget package.
You can see an example here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/VotXnj
I however, would modify the original JSON, to can be deserialized to a `Dictionary<string,string>` instead of creating classes for this reason

Comment: There are various ways to approach this: 1. You could just keep the read-in json as `string`, 2. you could deserialize it to something rather dynamic as JsonElement for example or JsonNode ... or 3. you can deserialize it to Dictionary or 4. a custom model. It's up to you what is the best approach for your requirements.